# Stumbling in Org Mode -- Capture

Tags: org-mode

Very impressed with what I have seen in Org Mode so far. And who knows, may be, I will switch over to Emacs from vim. :)

Here is what is part of my .emacs:

```el
(setq org-default-notes-file (concat org-directory "/notes.org"))

(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("t" "Todo" entry (file+headline "~/Documents/organize/org-mode/todo.org" "Tasks")
         "* TODO %?\n %i\n %a")))

(setq org-agenda-files '("~/Documents/organize/org-mode/"))
```

There is a directory ~/Documents/organize/org-mode. It has todo.org and notes.org files.

Yet when I start emacs, it produces an error: `Symbol's value as variable is void: org-directory` and when I try C-c c (tied to org-capture), it produces a window asking me to select a capture template. Options are: Task, Customize and Abort. Customize leads to a complicated dialog. And Task leads to an error: `Target buffer .notes for file+headline not in Org mode.`

I am new to Emacs and did not even remotely get what is happening here.

What do I need to do to go beyond this?

Comment: The variable `org-directory` will not be defined until `org` is loaded, so if you want to use it you should write something like `(with-eval-after-load 'org (setq org-default-notes-file (expand-file-name "notes.org" org-directory)))`. Is `file+handling` meant to read `file+headline`? Can you clarify what you have bound `C-c C` to (note that letter case matters)? Is it the command `org-capture`? You can check what command a key sequence is bound to by typing `C-h k` or `M-x describe-key RET` before typing out the key sequence.

Comment: @Basil Thanks. So, can I just ignore the warning and open my org files like there is no error? Yes. `file+handling` was meant to be `file+headline`. Emacs wont let me copy that text. So, had to key it in and the error crept in. And the key is `C-c c` and it is the command `org-capture`. I have edited the question to correct both the errors.

Comment: No, you shouldn't ignore the warning because it shouldn't be arising and its cause could be causing further trouble down the line. Have you tried replacing your `org-default-notes-file`-setting code with my suggestion? Alternatively you could just set `org-default-notes-file` to a hard-coded filename, as opposed to one constructed from the variable `org-directory`.

Comment: @Basil Your first suggestion did it. Thanks. Will you please post it as an answer? I will then accept it.

Comment: Glad it worked. I am not an experienced moderator, but my impression is that simple support issues like this can just be closed, as the answer may be of limited help to others. Having said that, I'll be happy to write up an aswer if you or anyone else asks again.